# Passing UI-Router state params from parent to child consistently

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state, parameters

I have the following UI-Router state definitions (trimmed down to only applicable aspects for brevity):

```
 .state('ep.perma', {
    url: '/:permalink',
    params: {permalink: ''}, //default
    templateUrl: 'views/conference/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })

  .state('ep.perma.login', {
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl: 'views/dialogs/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
  })

  .state('ep.perma.register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'views/dialogs/register.html',
    controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
  })
```

The :permalink parameter in the parent ep.perma state could be anything, but let's say it's 'acb123'. The login and register states each have an sref link to toggle to the others state in their html. Everything works fine if you go to the parent ep.perma state as the url initally. You can switch between login and register all day long and the :permalink parameter is persisted.

However if you navigate to the login or register state via a URL .../acb123/login or .../abc123/register initially everything is OK. But then if you then try to switch from login to register or the other way around by (depending on which URL you went to 1st) clicking the SREF link in the html, the :permalink param reference is lost. So, it I am at .../abc123/login, the sref for register in logins html should be .../abc123/register, but is //register instead. It's there on the initial load for either URL, but not in that html sref to go directly to the other.

This only happens if going to either the login or register child state directly via URL. If I go tot the parent ep.perma URL .../abc123 initially everything is fine.

Any thoughts on why this happens and/or how to address this? I found digging around here before posting this that I can pass the param(s) via resolves from the parent then consume them in the children, but do not want to end up with .../abc123/abc123/login if not accessing directly via the url. I am also not 100% clear on how to set them in the child state (only the controller per the example [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha)

I need for users to be able to got to either login or register via direct URL and switch between them having the initial specified :permalink parameter persist like it does if going directly to the parent as the initial URL.

TIA

Comment: Could you give a more solid use case? I have a severe case of tired and it's hard to parse your use case paragraph. *Why* are you trying to achieve what you are trying to achieve, rather than *how* you want to achieve it.

Comment: Working on a plunkr to try and show this but there are not real keen on going directly to URL's. The why seems less relevant than the how... but the "why" is:

Comment: Because the permalink param gives the illusion to the user that they are on their own sub-site and if they bookmark the URL to login (or any other route that requires login) but have not yet registered, they will need the toggle to work as expected.

Comment: ui-sref="ep.perma.login({permalink: permalink})" and then in your controller, something like $scope.permalink = $stateParams.permalink;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wanted to help, to give some idea, so there is [a working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rQRG6ZpXLWADX9md1YV5?p=preview). The point is, it is working as is. You can even navigate to direct url (in address bar) and it will still work:

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/rQRG6ZpXLWADX9md1YV5/#/bara/register

Also these links would work:

```
<a href="#/abc123">/abc123</a>
<a href="#/abc123/login">/abc123/login</a>
<a href="#/abc123/register">/abc123/register</a>

<a href="#/def456">/def456</a>
<a href="#/def456/login">/def456/login</a>
<a href="#/def456/register">/def456/register</a>

<a ui-sref="ep.perma({permalink:'xyz789'})">
<a ui-sref="ep.perma.login({permalink:'xyz789'})">
<a ui-sref="ep.perma.register({permalink:'xyz789'})">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rQRG6ZpXLWADX9md1YV5?p=preview) and try to compare what is different in your code. Or make it broken... to continue on it and fix it.

Comment: Turns out it was a combination of things... 1) need to ref the params in the SREF(s). 2) Login and Register are modals, so need to use parent instead of DOT notation. 3) Had to factor in the stateParams gotcha detailed at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha. The base plunkr lead me to resolving all of them so thanks much for that!

Comment: @DDurham that should be an answer by itself...would love to upvote :)